# SimCLR, augmentation generates one images instead of two

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning, data-augmentation

I am working in augmentations of SimCLR, from one image, we must generate two. but if I plot my output, it displays only one image . I can't understand why

```
def augment_ops()
....
    return image
 def preprocess_image_train(image):
   
    image1 = augment_ops(image)
    image2 = augment_ops(image)

    return image1, image2
output = preprocess_image_train(img1)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you call the function ,as two images are returned, like this :

```
output1,output2 = preprocess_image_train(img1)
```

And show them separately?

```
plt.imshow(output1)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(output2)
plt.show()
```